# How to get user address and phone number from google auth

Tags: node.js, google-api, passport.js

Iam using passport.js for authentication using passport-google-oauth20,

I was wondering how can get user information like address, phone number ? so far i just can get information like email, name, profile but not address and phone number. how can access user data address after login with google ?

Is there any API to access this user address and phone number ? what should I do ?

this is my code :

**Passport setup**

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        //options for the google strategy
        callbackURL: keys.origin.url + '/api/auth/google/redirect',
        clientID: keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
        userProfileURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo'
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
          console.log(profile);
    })

);
```

**Route**

```
routes.get('/auth/google',passport.authenticate("google",{
    scope: ["profile", "email"]
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    routes.get('/auth/google',passport.authenticate("google",{
    scope: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.agerange.read'
  ]
}));
```

this returns the user data